# Grouping Dataframe by two Columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas

This is a continuation to a problem I've asked previously in my post history. I have values that were summed up using REGEX and I want to further develop my results by grouping these values by columns and have looked at using the groupby function to no success. Below is a screenshot of my new df and the columns I would want to group by (subID and Label) and want to have the sum of New Value with those groups. Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: New DF]

Comment: Please share your code, what have you tried, what behavior did you expect vs what you got? This makes it much easier to help you (e.g. is the problem that you don't understand how groupby works, or did you just forget the axis parameter etc...), and also shows that you put in some effort before posting :-)

Answer (score 0):

df.groupby(['sub_id', 'label'])['New Value'].sum()